# Report for ISP versus Custom Variable in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, visitor-statistic

I push a custom variable like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'userName', '', 1]);
```

I can see their list from the Google Analytics menu: Audience/Custom/Custom Variables. I can add city/country/browser etc. as secondary dimension. But I need to know which user comes from which ISP. Is it possible to create a report for this. Like:

```
Custom Variable ------ ISP -------- Visits
Michael ----------- Aa Telecom ------ 12
Daniel ----------- Aa Telecom --------- 3
John -------------  Bb Communication --- 25
```